# How to switch between Twitter streams

Tags: api, twitter

I have access to the Twitter stream gardenhose. Though I want to use it, at times I want to scale down the level of input as I'm testing my code.

How do I switch between gardenhose and spritzer?

I only see where you call the stream via `http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json`. Do you simply omit your userid to get the scaled-down version of the stream?

Comment: Realized you cannot omit your userid as it is mandatory for any stream.  Still looking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking the answer is "Use another account."  I see where where you have to get a key and access tokens.  I'm assuming these are given to an account and each account only has one for accessing the stream.  Thus, if you wanted to scale down, simply use an account that has not been granted access to gardenhose.

Might not be the most elegant answer, but I believe it is AN answer...